# No brake pressure after Starting the car

Tags: brakes, vw, golf, brake-fluid

I have a 2003 vw golf and i have a brake problem.
After i have bleed the brakes and feel that they are working I jump in my cart to start it bu as soon as I do so it just looses all brakes and ive done this many times over and over

Another weird thing:

- I can pour in liters and liters of oil but only a small ammount of oil accually comes out but I have no oil on the floor.

Comment: Are you sure you put the brake fluid (I suppose that's what you mean with oil) in the right opening?

Comment: During the brake bleeding procedure, did you use VCDS / VAG COM or another plug in diagnostic tool to perform the bleed of the ABS unit?  Are you using a pressure bleeder to push the fluid through and pedal pressure and a non-return line on the bleed nipple to pump the fluid though?

Comment: Can you add a photo of where you are pouring the oil in?